# Problem In Adding Flexslider To Slideshow

Tags: javascript

Hello i Have Create A Views Slideshow Using Views And Jquery Cycle But I Am Installing Flexslider Module But I Can Able To See A Slide Sidebar I Am Also Placing The Flexslieder Into Libriaries

Check My Link Adclof.com

Comment: what is the problem? what did you do so far? what is the error in error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use the flexslider module with views integration, views slideshow and flexslider views style are different modules. They each provide a different style for your view!